# Could not resolve reference external Dll Docker

Tags: c#, docker, dll, docker-build

I'm trying to use the docker build command in an application that has external dll references, but the same error always occurs. The external namespace is `DllGeneratorExtensions`
Docker Version: `4.5.1`
.NET Version: `.NET 6 / (3.1 old project version with same error)`

> Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "DllGeneratorExtensions". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [/src/ConsumerExternalDll.csproj]

The DockerFile was created by Visual Studio itself, but when I run the project using docker by Visual Studio, no error occurs, only if I try to build it using the command itself.

I created a test application to try to simulate the error.
This is the dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ConsumerExternalDll.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./ConsumerExternalDll.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "ConsumerExternalDll.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ConsumerExternalDll.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ConsumerExternalDll.dll"]
```

This is the dll reference in the project

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="DllGeneratorExtensions">
      <HintPath>..\output\Debug\net6.0\DllGeneratorExtensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

I already tried to copy the file in the build, but nothing solves the problem

Command executed
`docker build -t dllextensions .`

Output error:

````
  > [build 7/7] RUN dotnet build "ConsumerExternalDll.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build:
#15 0.579 MSBuild version 17.3.1+2badb37d1 for .NET
#15 1.090   Determining projects to restore...
#15 1.388   All projects are up-to-date for restore.
#15 1.578 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.401/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "DllGeneratorExtensions". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [/src/ConsumerExternalDll.csproj]
#15 2.404 /src/Program.cs(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DllGeneratorExtensions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/src/ConsumerExternalDll.csproj]
#15 2.430
#15 2.430 Build FAILED.
#15 2.430
#15 2.430 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.401/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "DllGeneratorExtensions". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [/src/ConsumerExternalDll.csproj]
#15 2.430 /src/Program.cs(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DllGeneratorExtensions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/src/ConsumerExternalDll.csproj]
#15 2.430     1 Warning(s)
#15 2.430     1 Error(s)
#15 2.431
#15 2.431 Time Elapsed 00:00:01.78
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet build "ConsumerExternalDll.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build]: exit code: 1
```
````

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Visual Studio for Mac version 17.4.
I managed to workaround the issue by changing 2 things:

1. I changed the path to the dll and put it **inside** the solution
   folder,
2. Then I added a COPY command in the Dockerfile where I was
   able to reference the updated dll path.

In your case, the result would be similar to:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ConsumerExternalDll.csproj", "."]
COPY ["output/Debug/net6.0/DllGeneratorExtensions.dll", "."]
```